# Merging default values with kwargs, any better syntax?

Tags: python

I have a method that accepts variable arguments and merges user supplied options with default options, e.g

```
def run(domain, **kwargs):
    options = {'opt1': 'abc', 'opt2': 'def'}

    if 'opt1' in kwargs:
        options['opt1'] = kwargs['opt1']
    if 'opt2' in kwargs:
        options['opt2'] = kwargs['opt2']
```

Is there any better writing than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
def run(domain, **kwargs):
  options = {'opt1': 'abc', 'opt2': 'def'}
  options = {a:kwargs.get(a, b) for a, b in options.items()}
```